# Pass custom data to service worker sync?

Tags: service-worker, background-sync

I need to make a POST request and send some data. I'm using the service worker `sync` to handle offline situation.

But is there a way to pass the POST data to the service worker, so it makes the same request again?

Cause apparently the current solution is to store requests in some client side storage and after client gets connection - get the requests info from the storage and then send them.

Any more elegant way?

PS: I thought about just making the service worker send message to the application code so it does the request again ... but unfortunately it doesn't know the exact client that registered the service worker :(

Answer (score 6):

You can use [fetch-sync](https://github.com/sdgluck/fetch-sync)

or i use postmessage to fix this problem, which i agree that indexedDB looks trouble.

1. first of all, i send the message from html.

   ```
   // send message to serviceWorker
   function sync (url, options) {
     navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({type: 'sync', url, options})
   }
   ```
2. i got this message in serviceworker, and then i store it.

   ```
   const syncStore = {}
   self.addEventListener('message', event => {
     if(event.data.type === 'sync') {
       // get a unique id to save the data
       const id = uuid()
       syncStore[id] = event.data
       // register a sync and pass the id as tag for it to get the data
       self.registration.sync.register(id)
     }
     console.log(event.data)
   })
   ```
3. in the sync event, i got the data and fetch

   ```
   self.addEventListener('sync', event => {
     // get the data by tag
     const {url, options} = syncStore[event.tag]
     event.waitUntil(fetch(url, options))
   })
   ```

it works well in my test, what's more you can delete the memory store after the fetch

what's more, you may want to send back the result to the page. i will do this in the same way by postmessage.

1. as now i have to communicate between each other, i will change the fucnction sync into this way

   ```
   // use messagechannel to communicate
   sendMessageToSw (msg) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // Create a Message Channel
       const msg_chan = new MessageChannel()

   // Handler for recieving message reply from service worker
   msg_chan.port1.onmessage = event => {
     if(event.data.error) {
       reject(event.data.error)
     } else {
       resolve(event.data)
     }
   }

   navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(msg, [msg_chan.port2])


     })
   }
   // send message to serviceWorker
   // you can see that i add a parse argument
   // this is use to tell the serviceworker how to parse our data
   function sync (url, options, parse) {
     return sendMessageToSw({type: 'sync', url, options, parse})
   }
   ```
2. i also have to change the message event, so that i can pass the port to sync event

   ```
   self.addEventListener('message', event => {
     if(isObject(event.data)) {
       if(event.data.type === 'sync') {
         // in this way, you can decide your tag
         const id = event.data.id || uuid()
         // pass the port into the memory stor
         syncStore[id] = Object.assign({port: event.ports[0]}, event.data)
         self.registration.sync.register(id)
       }
     }
   })
   ```
3. up to now, we can handle the sync event

   ```
   self.addEventListener('sync', event => {
     const {url, options, port, parse} = syncStore[event.tag] || {}
     // delete the memory
     delete syncStore[event.tag]
     event.waitUntil(fetch(url, options)
       .then(response => {
         // clone response because it will fail to parse if it parse again
         const copy = response.clone()
         if(response.ok) {
           // parse it as you like
           copy[parse]()
           .then(data => {
             // when success postmessage back
             port.postMessage(data)
           })
         } else {
           port.postMessage({error: response.status})
         }
       })
       .catch(error => {
         port.postMessage({error: error.message})
       })
     )
   })
   ```

At the end. you cannot use postmessage to send response directly.Because it's illegal.So you need to parse it, such as text, json, blob, etc. i think that's enough.

As you have mention that, you may want to open the window.
i advice that you can use serviceworker to send a notification.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {

  const title = 'i am a fucking test'
  const options = {
    body: 'Yay it works.',
  }
  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options))
})
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {

  event.notification.close()

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow('https://yoursite.com')
  )
})
```

when the client click we can open the window.

Comment: That looks very nice ;) ... One thing that I'm thinking about though - is there a way to `return` the result of this `fetch` request to the page? ... Cause sending message from service worker to app is possible, but you need to know the exact client who started the sync. And also - can we handle the situation of sending the response back to the page in such way: 1) if the page is closed - to open the page? 2) page is still opened - show some custom message with the response.

Comment: i update the answer.it includes method to send back. We also can do some stuff when we send back the response.i will do the two thing you mentioned by using notifications.

Comment: the notification part is not complete.if you are interested in it. you can google it.

Comment: I'm stumbling upon issues, when I just use `client.postMessage()` in the service worker. Scenario: one-way communication from SW to app. Inside the promise chain links of `event.waitUntil()` in the sync event listener this leads to a non finishing Promise or something like this. Did you ever see this problem with your `port.postMessage(data)` (I know, that this a port from the main app though)? I guess I need to close the connection somewhere.

Comment: **Regarding the last comment:** forget about it. It was a really stupid error in my new Promise parameter function (no call of `resolve()`.

Answer (score 0):

To comunicate with the serviceworker I use a trick:

in the fetch eventlistener I put this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  if (event.request.url.includes("sw_messages.js")) {
    var zib = "some data";
    event.respondWith(new Response("window.msg=" + JSON.stringify(zib) + ";", {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'
      }
    }));
  }

  return;
});
```

then, in the main html I just add:

```
<script src="sw_messages.js"></script>
```

as the page loads, global variable msg will contain (in this example) "some data".