# is it possible to do POST REQUEST in background sync [Service Worker]?

Tags: javascript

is it possible to do POST REQUEST in background sync IN FRONTEND (SERVICE WORKERs)? 
User put video  to "uploads queue" when offline and it uploads when "online" event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling File Uploads When Offline With Service Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709654/handling-file-uploads-when-offline-with-service-worker)

Comment: i have ready app using VUE JS : https://github.com/kostia7alania/video_uploader_vue
AND I KNOW ALL ABOUT <input type=file> events;) 
I ask about real experience  when you upload large files in background

Answer (score 1):

Offline upload video should return an error or button disable flag, i think.

Put video to "uploads queue" not correct, because User can change their mind

Comment: it's government web-service;) User can't change decide.